# How does one compute $(\text{id}\otimes T)\rho$ for a possibly entangled quantum state $\rho$?

Tags: quantum-information

Suppose that $T$ is a quantum channel on a marginal system. 
How does one compute $(\text{id}\otimes T)\rho$ for a possibly entangled quantum state $\rho$ on the composite system?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Can you provide some context, and even better an example of the kind of $\rho$ and $T$ you are looking at? Otherwise I would just say that you compute that product the same way you compute any product between two matrices

Comment: Well, take for instance $T$ defined on the system $B$ by $T(\rho)=\text{tr}(\rho)\sigma$ for a fixed density operator sigma. Is it true if $\sigma=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, then $(\text{id}\otimes T)(|0,1\rangle\langle 1,0|)=0$ whilst $(\text{id}\otimes T)(|0,0\rangle\langle 0,0|)=|0,\psi\rangle\langle 0,\psi|$?

Comment: you can add such examples to your question by editing the post. Also, in what spaces do $\rho$ and $\sigma$ live in your example? And is tr a partial or a total trace? Finally, why can't you just use the regular matrix multiplication rules? Explain what exactly you don't find clear